# connect() returns "Operation now in progress" on blocking socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, timeout

I have a blocking socket (at least it appears so in following code):

```
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock < 0) {
            ERROR("%s: error opening socket", __func__);
            return (RESP_ERROR);
    }

    t.tv_sec = timeout;
    t.tv_usec = 0;

    int rf = fcntl(sock, F_GETFD);
    ERROR("fcntl ret=%d, ret & O_NONBLOCK = %d", rf, rf & O_NONBLOCK);

    if ((setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&t, sizeof (t)) < 0)
        || (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&t, sizeof (t)))) {
            strerror_r(errno, err, 254);
            ERROR("%s: error on setsockopt -> %s", __func__, err);
            close(sock);
            return (RESP_ERROR);
    }

    rf = fcntl(sock, F_GETFD);
    ERROR("after select fcntl ret=%d, ret & O_NONBLOCK = %d", rf, rf & O_NONBLOCK);

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&dst, sizeof (dst)) != 0) {
            strerror_r(errno, err, 254);
            ERROR("%s: error on connect -> %s", __func__, err);
            close(sock);
            return (RESP_ERROR);
    }
```

And this is from the log:

> Mar  6 10:42:04 tcpclient: fcntl ret=0, ret & O_NONBLOCK = 0

> Mar  6 10:42:04 tcpclient: after select fcntl ret=0, ret & O_NONBLOCK = 0

> Mar 6 10:42:14 tcpclient:  authenticate: error on connect -> Operation now in progress

It appears this is a blocking socket but returns an error typical for non-blocking? Linux is 2.6.18-308.el5. Any ideas?

Comment: `timeout` has which value?

Comment: To verify my answer I'd like to do some tests. Therefore I'd like to know how `dst` had been initialised before being passed in to `connect()`. Are you sure its member `sin_family` had been set correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `timeout` is not `0` the call to `connect()` times out and returns. This happens independently of whether a connection was established or not.

From the moment the time-out expired `connect()` behaves as if called on a non-blocking socket.

Referring this case (verbatim from `man connect` and ignore "*immediately*" below):

> EINPROGRESS
>
> The socket is nonblocking and the connection cannot be completed immediately.  It is possible to select(2) or poll(2) for completion by selecting the socket for writing.  After  select(2)  indicates  writability,  use
>                 getsockopt(2)  to read the SO_ERROR option at level SOL_SOCKET to determine whether connect() completed successfully (SO_ERROR is zero) or unsuccessfully (SO_ERROR is one of the usual error codes listed here, explain‐
>                 ing the reason for the failure).

---

Btw: Could someone confirm this is standard behaviour, and for this **explicitly** mentioned somewhere?

`man 7 socket` states (italics by me):

> SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO
>
> Specify the receiving or sending timeouts until reporting an error.  [...] if no data has been transferred and the timeout has been reached then -1 is returned with errno set to EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK *just as if the socket was
>                 specified to be nonblocking*.  [...] Timeouts only have effect for system calls that perform socket I/O (e.g., read(2), recvmsg(2), send(2),
>                 sendmsg(2)); timeouts have no effect for select(2), poll(2), epoll_wait(2), etc.

No word regarding `connect()`so I'm unsure my answer does hold.

Comment: It appears "From the moment the time-out expired connect() behaves as if called on a non-bocking socket." this is the key part. Would close(sock) stop this operation?

Comment: Sure `close()` invalides the socket. However the OS might keep its hand on the address:port for some time. To resue the address:port prior to the OS released it you might specify the socket option `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Comment: I don't see why setting a read or write timeout would affect connect(). The only way I'm aware of to get a timed-out connect is to do it in non-blocking mode with select().

Answer (score 2):

Try it with `if (connect(...) < 0)`. You may not be getting an error at all.

NB blocking mode is the default. You don't have to set it.